# Using Python android.py module without SL4A

Tags: android, python, sl4a, android-scripting

Is there a way to use `android.py` module without installing SL4A?

I mean I have Python running on android successfully from Terminal Emulator.
Can I use that module without installing that layer (or if I can't install it anymore)?

Comment: if `android.py` doesn't depend on any other `SL4A` libraries, you can copy it in python `lib` and start using...

Comment: @avasal: unfortunately, it needs some connection that sl4a creates when starts the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the SL4A package provides the facade to make device API calls, acting as a middleman. Without it you *might* be able to import it, but you could not be able to make any API calls.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is the answer I've been waiting for. But not the one I would be satisfied with.